# What are the Drawbacks/ Caveats / Limitations of using a Non-Authoritative Server over a Fully Authoritative Server for Multiplayer Networking?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, server, multiplayer

Our Team is  developing a **Fast-Paced Arena FPS** game with a maximum of 10 Players per match(5v5) for **Mobile Platforms** using **Unity**.
 We're really in a dilemma on whether to use a Non-Authoritative or Fully Authoritative  Server.

---

**Non-Authoritative Approach** : Each player just  sends snapshots about it's current position to other Players and Remote Procedure Calls are called for special events like Firing a Weapon or triggering an Explosion. Physics is simulated Locally.

Thinking on Using ***Photon Unity Networking (PUN)*** for this approach, because of Mature API and *Master-Client Model* and *Advanced Relays*.

---

**Authoritative Approach** : The clients just send their Input Snapshots to a Dedicated Server, where the game is simulated using the Inputs and the game state is sent back to the clients, who just Renders it.

Thinking of Using ***Photon Bolt*** for this approach, because of **Built-In** *Client-Side Prediction* and *Lag Compensation* which is crucial while using a Dedicated Server.

---

So, Apart from making it easy for Cheaters to hack my game, what are the drawbacks/Limitations of using a Non-Authoritative Server over Authoritative one? Is Server Authority required in a mobile game? What are *your recommendations* for the type of game we're trying to make?

Also, How bad(or good) is the overhead of running an *Unity Instance* on a Dedicated Server(In Headless Mode)?

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, Apart from making it easy for Cheaters to hack my game, what are
>   the drawbacks/Limitations of using a Non-Authoritative Server over
>   Authoritative one?

De-synchronization is a considerable drawback. It is ok if the physics simulated locally does not affect the functional outcome of the game.

However, for example, if the trajectory of a rocket from a launcher is simulated locally with physics, and whether it hits another player or not is decided locally too, you will end up with players getting killed despite *seemingly* not being hit by one.

In more serious cases, you might end up with players experiencing completely different outcomes of the match on their machines.

> Is Server Authority required in a mobile game?

Not necessarily.

> What are your recommendations for the type of game we're trying to
>   make?

For multiplayer games, typically its recommended to have an authoritative server that does calculations for important events (e.g hit by a bullet).

To prevent choppy movement and actions, you would need to implement some form of interpolation/prediction/dead reckoning client side, and do corrections when your authoritative server replies.

> Also, How bad(or good) is the overhead of running an Unity Instance on
>   a Dedicated Server(In Headless Mode)?

Im not sure what overhead you are comparing to, but typically a Unity instance ran without graphics and in batchmode as a server is able to effectively handle a multiplayer game of 10 people pretty well.